# How to avoid call observe() twice?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, observers

I have an observer inside a function. I call this function firstly in my activity's `onCreate()` and it works fine.  After that when I call this function again, the code inside my observer is called twice. How can I prevent this behaviour?

> Here is my function with observer

```
private lateinit var word: String

fun addViews() {

    viewModel.getQuestion()

    viewModel.questionResponse.observe(this, { it ->
        this.word = it.data.word

            createAnswerTextView(this.word.length)

        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT:**

What I wanted to do is refreshing the layout by removing and adding views in these steps.

1. Creating text views as long as word length. ( `addViews()`
   does it for me )
2. Removing those views.
3. Creating text views again as long as new word length. (
   `addViews()` does it for me )

I couldn't create the observer only once in activity's `onCreate()` method. Because I needed to use addViews function and its observer multi times.

`viewModel.questionResponse.removeObservers(this)` didn't work too.

But adding `viewModel.questionResponse = MutableLiveData()` in function where I remove my text views and clear value of my properties solved my problem.

Comment: by simply not calling it twice..

Comment: or by leaving some flag that its already observed

Comment: You should call `viewModel.questionResponse.observe(...)` only once in the Activity's `onCreate()` method.

Comment: you're not supposed to start observing in a function that is called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your observer in "onViewCreated" if you are working in a fragment, or in your onCreateView if you are working in an activity.

Also, in your fragment you should define your viewmodel as:

```
val yourviewModel by activityViewModels<YourViewModel>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        yourviewModel.yourVariable.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
          // some function to do
        }
}
```

And in your activity as:

```
val yourviewModel by viewModels<YourViewModel>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        yourviewModel.yourVariable.observe(this) {
          // some function to do
        }
}
```

If you don't want to do this, there is another way and it is just to remove all the observers:

```
fun addViews() {

    viewModel.getQuestion()

    // add this line
    viewModel.questionResponse.removeObservers(this)
    viewModel.questionResponse.observe(this, { it ->
        this.word = it.data.word

            createAnswerTextView(this.word.length)

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

always call an observer inside `onCreate` in activity. You are registering your observer every-time you call `addViews()` function. Just move below code to inside onCreate

```
viewModel.questionResponse.observe(this, { it ->
        this.word = it.data.word

            createAnswerTextView(this.word.length)

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

after getting data you should call
viewModel?.getData()?.removeObservers(this)

Comment: Mosayeb Masoumi, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.